# Is there any alternative to libVLC to stream and display rtsp?

Tags: rtsp, lgpl, libvlc

i have problem with the GPL license that libVLC only support , is there any alternative ?
something that is lgpl or other none gpl ?

Comment: On which platform should this alternative run?

Comment: windows and also mac and linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is one LGPL, multiplatform, and capable of both streaming and display option: [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/). Note that not all codecs available for GStreamer are LGPL, however.

(The other option that comes to mind is [LIVE555 Streaming Media](http://live555.com/liveMedia/), which is LGPL but doesn't handle display.)

Answer (score 2):

LibVLC has started to switch to LGPL.

http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=commit;h=36ab287e77e9df059f261ed1cfb13fc4674182ec

Answer (score 0):

GStreamer should work as mentioned above, also consider trying FFMPEG (which I've always preferred to GStreamer myself) It works with streaming audio/video and is LGPL.

Comment: i need display also , not only codacs

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood what you meant by display. Thought you meant played video.

Answer (score 0):

How about [FFMpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/). FFMpeg can be used to stream Media contents and would work on Windows, Linux and Mac as well.

Moreover, FFmpeg is free software licensed under the LGPL or GPL.